# How to correct the outcome from Mann-Whitney U test

Tags: r

I am using R Markdown and analysing a data set. The following is a sample Pre and Post test scores.

```
PREOP_MPTA POSTOP_MPTA DELTA-MPTA  
83  84  1
84  90  6
80  90  10
86  88  2
82  78  -4
86  89  3
84  88  4
85  90  5
```

Data = DLO_HYBRID
The 2 variables to compare are PREOP_MPTA and POSTOP_MPTA

I assessed the normality of data using a Shapiro test and the p value is 0.01. So, data is not normally distributed.

```
shapiro.test(DLO_HYBRID$PREOP_MPTA)
shapiro.test(DLO_HYBRID$POSTOP_MPTA)
shapiro.test(DLO_HYBRID$DELTA_MPTA)
```

I used Mann-Whitney u test to compare the difference between the 2 samples but I am getting a message saying that one of the variables is not found.

```
wilcox.test(PREOP_MPTA,POSTOP_MPTA, alternative = ("two.sided"),mu = 0, paired = FALSE, exact = NULL, correct = TRUE,conf.int = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, tol.root = 1e-4, digits.rank = Inf, DLO_HYBRID)
```

I get the following message
Error in wilcox.test(PREOP_MPTA, POSTOP_MPTA, alternative = ("two.sided"),  :
object 'PREOP_MPTA' not found

How to sort this out? Is my code for wilcox correct?

Comment: Try `wilcox.test(DLO_HYBRID$PREOP_MPTA, DLO_HYBRID$POSTOP_MPTA)`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but had the following message: Warning: cannot compute exact p-value with ties
 Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  DLO_HYBRID$PREOP_MPTA and DLO_HYBRID$POSTOP_MPTA
W = 46.5, p-value = 5.866e-07
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Comment: That's OK. That's just saying that you have ties in your data. It shows a highly significant difference between the two vectors.

Comment: but when I tried to assign it like that: MPTA_WILCOX <- wilcox.test(DLO_HYBRID$PREOP_MPTA, DLO_HYBRID$POSTOP_MPTA). It gives the following message:Warning: cannot compute exact p-value with ties

Comment: I want to be able to convert the p values to a readable format. I use the following code from Pixiedust package to get p value with t test. MPTA_ttest <- t.test(Pair(PREOP_MPTA , POSTOP_MPTA) ~ 1 , data=DLO_HYBRID)
dust(MPTA_ttest) %>% 
  sprinkle(cols = c("estimate", "std.error", "statistic"),
           round = 3) %>% 
  sprinkle(cols = "p.value", fn = quote(pvalString(value)))